# Call a method over a collection to add to another collection

Tags: java, collections

I have to keep writing code that is longer than I would like, and I have to do it lots of times.

```
Collection<MiClase> collection1 = new ArrayList<MiClase>;
Collection<String> collection2 = new ArrayList<String>;
// I currently do this
for (MiClase c : collection1){
    collection2.add(c.nombre()); // nombre() returns String
}
```

Is there something to make it shorter?

```
// I want something like
collection2.addAll(collection1, MiClase.nombre);
```

Comment: If something like this existed it would be in the JavaDocs, and it's not :(.  So unfortunately you are stuck with what you are currently doing unless you want to take Dukeling's comment about reflection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not built-in java function that does that¹. You could use Guavas '[Collections2#transform(collection, function)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#transform%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29)'

So, your code would look something like

```
// nombres = collections2, miClasses = collection1
nombres.addAll(Collections2.transform(miClasses, new Function() {
    @Override
    public String apply (MiClasse miClasse) {
        return miClasse.nombre();
    }
}));
```

But this is really cumbersome and may be an overkill just to remove a simple loop.

**EDIT**

1 - As pointed out by A.R.S., not built-in before Java 8 lambda expression and improved collection API. A link with some cool examples: http://www.javabeat.net/2012/05/enhanced-collections-api-in-java-8-supports-lambda-expressions/

Comment: The fact that Java does not support lambda expressions (or, at least, will not until Java 8) makes this very cumbersome, since we need to extend/instantiate a class just for a single method (it's kind of like faking lambda functions through anonymous classes). I would suggest sticking with the loop as well, +1 anyway.

Comment: @A.R.S. Yep, totally agree. I'm looking for Java 8 with lambda expressions and improved JVM boxing/unboxing.

Comment: i want this! so i need wait till new java :(

Answer (score 2):

More for completeness than anything else...

You could write a method to do this using [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29#Java):

```
static <A,B> void addAll(Collection<B> dest, Collection<A> source, String methodName)
      throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException
{
  for (A a: source)
  {
    // can optimize this to only get method once if all objects have same type
    Method m = a.getClass().getMethod(methodName);
    dest.add((B)m.invoke(a));
  }
}
```

**Usage / example:**

```
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> i = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
addAll(s, i, "toString");
System.out.println(s);
```

You could also add method parameters if you so wish.

[Test](http://ideone.com/cCj8JF).

**Why I would >>NOT<< recommend it**:

If throwing 3 exceptions doesn't have you worried yet... (sure, you could `try`-`catch`, but rather avoid exceptions altogether)

A few points of (human) failure: (these will all show up as runtime errors, but compile-time errors are preferred)

- The method name is misspelt
- The method doesn't even exist
- The method doesn't return an object of type `B`

Answer (score 0):

Two of few ways using [`Stream API`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

For,

```
Collection<MiClase> collection1 = new ArrayList<>;
Collection<String> collection2 = new ArrayList<>;
```

And `MiClase#nombre` returning `String` as OP mentioned:

```
collection1.stream()
        .map(MiClase::nombre)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .forEach(collection2::add);
```

Or

```
collection2.addAll(collection1.stream()
        .map(MiClase::nombre)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```